# Register the same type to multiple interfaces

Tags: unity-container

It is possible to register one type to multiple interfaces?

I have class that implement two interfaces

```
MyService : IService1, IServier2 {}
```

I would like to register this type for both interfaces.

```
container.RegisterType<IService1, MyService>(CreateLifetime());
container.RegisterType<IService2, MyService>(CreateLifetime());
```

Unfortunately during after resolving I have two different instances. I tried use common lifetime but then I got message that I can't.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9075733/750065). If you use a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` it is sufficient to register the first mapping `IService1` -> `MyService` with that lifetime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I usually write this:

```
      .RegisterType<MyService>(CreateLifeTime())
      .RegisterType<IService1, MyService>()
      .RegisterType<IService2, MyService>();
```

Of course with a TransientLifetimeManager, you still will get two different instances of MyService.

The code above works with `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, `PerThreadLifetimeManager`.

Comment: Can you give the equivalent in app.config XML syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by config as well:

```
<register type="MyService" name="MyServiceName">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
</register>
<register type="IService1" mapTo="MyService" />
<register type="IService2" mapTo="MyService" />
```

Comment: It does not work Resolve<IService1>() and Resolve<IService2>()  returns 2 different instances.

Answer (score 0):

I based my answer on [@StephenTunney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33684835/1733377), but I couldn't get his to work.

You can do this by config as well:

```
<register type="MyService" name="MyServiceName">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
</register>
<register type="IService1" mapTo="MyService">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
</register>
<register type="IService2" mapTo="MyService">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
</register>
```

Note that the `name="MyServiceName"` is optional and only required if you plan on doing [named instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853(v=pandp.20).aspx).