# Register same implementation for multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, servicestack, inversion-of-control

I have a class that implements a number of interfaces

```
public class AwesomeThingClass: IAwesome<Thing>, IAwesomeThing {
    // parameterized constructor, so can't use RegisterAutowiredAs
    public AwesomeThingClass(IClient client, string connectionString) {} 
}
```

It encapsulates multithreading operations with limited cardinality (I mean, only N of such operations are allowed to run simultaneously) by using semaphores.

However, if I register it with IoC using something like

```
container.Register<IAwesome<Thing>>(cont => new AwesomeThingClass(cont.Resolve<IClient>(), connStr))
container.Register<IAwesomeThing>(cont => new AwesomeThingClass(cont.Resolve<IClient>(), connStr))
```

I end up with two instances that could be resolved using `IAwesome<Thing>` and `IAwesomeThing`, which allows to run 2*N operations. I definitely need same instance resolved for both interfaces. Are there any way to achieve this, except for manually instantiating class and [registering instance](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#register-instances)?

This question is essentially similar to [Register the same type to multiple interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115298/register-the-same-type-to-multiple-interfaces), but it's not it's duplicate, as I'm using ServiceStack IoC container (`Func` at the time of writing), while that question is about `Unity`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a simple solution specialized for ServiceStack IoC but you could also use a `Lazy<T>` to return the same value from both of your lambdas.

```
var lazy = new Lazy<AwesomeThingClass>(() =>
    new AwesomeThingClass(container.Resolve<IClient>(), connStr));

container.Register<IAwesome<Thing>>(cont => lazy.Value);
container.Register<IAwesomeThing>(cont => lazy.Value);
```

(I'm assuming that the `cont` parameter of the lambda would be the same object as the `container` variable.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it's essentially the same as manually instantiating the class. The major problem is that dependencies are not auto-wired when using instance registration, and this is just lazy instance registration.

Comment: @J0HN But how do you want to get around the fact that you want to inject a custom parameter (`connStr`). That doesn't seem to work with auto-wiring at all.

Comment: it's either I don't understand something, or documentation is not clear, but it looks like using [custom factories](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#using-custom-factories) still trigger the autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just cast it:

```
container.Register<IAwesomeThing>(c => 
    new AwesomeThingClass(c.Resolve<IClient>(), connStr));

container.Register(c => (IAwesome<Thing>) c.Resolve<IAwesomeThing>()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but the problem here is that we loose compile-time type check. It's good as a workaround, but might lead to runtime errors if something AwesomeThingClass no longer implement `IAwesome<Thing>`.

Comment: @J0HN You'll still get a `suspicious cast` warning (from VS.NET or R#) if it can't find an type that implements both interfaces. Otherwise you'll find out pretty quickly when you try to use a Service or dependency that resolves `IAwesome<Thing>`.