# Unintended method exposure using inheritance with a generics typed class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I did my best with the title. What I am trying to accomplish is tiered modularity with dependency injection. Whether or not this design pattern is good is a question for [another forum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Because I am using dependency injection, I have interface/implementation pairs. This is the top-level inteface:

```
public interface IConfiguration<T> where T : ConfigData
{
    T GetConfig();
}
```

Where `ConfigData` is a simple class that exposes `get`/`set` properties like `LogLevel` and `Environment`.

There is a base implementation of the interface:

```
public abstract class ConfigurationBase<T> : IConfiguration
{
    protected ConfigData Config { get; set; }

    public T GetConfig()
    {
        return Config as T;
    }
}
```

Now for the dependency injection part of this! I have several interface/implementation pairs that hierarchically inherit from one another. Furthermore, their `protected Config` property also exposes more properties in each subsequent child class. Here are my interface/implementation signatures:

```
public interface IGeneralConfiguration : IConfiguration<GeneralConfigData>
public class GeneralConfiguration : ConfigurationBase<GeneralConfigData>, IGeneralConfiguration

public interface ILoginConfiguration : IConfiguration<LoginConfigData>, IGeneralConfiguration
public class LoginConfiguration : ConfigurationBase<LoginConfigData>, ILoginConfiguration

public interface IAppConfiguration : IConfiguration<AppConfigData>, ILoginConfiguration
public class AppConfiguration : ConfigurationBase<AppConfigData>, IAppConfiguration
```

Note that the inheritance scheme for the config data element is `ConfigData` → `GeneralConfigData` → `LoginConfigData` → `AppConfigData`. The config data element just exposes more properties specific to login/the application etc. (like `Username` or `StartUri`) in each child.

Now, I can use this configuration concept across all my modules. As far as dependency injection goes, resolving `IGeneralConfiguration`, `ILoginConfiguration` or `IAppConfiguration` will [yield the exact same instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115298/register-the-same-type-to-multiple-interfaces/47985842#47985842). However, now general modules only need to resolve `IGeneralConfiguration`, modules specific to login will only need to resolve `ILoginConfiguration`, and app-specific modules can resolve `IAppConfiugration`, all so that they can access parts of their config data specific to the concern they are trying to handle. This modularity allows me to create smaller side-apps that reuse modules from the main application without having to do a lot of custom coding (for example, I can reuse the login module without the need for referencing app-specific modules) as long as I slightly alter my dependency registration.

If you are still with me up to this point, the only problem with this model is that in all of my sub classes (that inherit from `ConfigurationBase<T>`), they all need the `ConfigData()` implementation from the interface above them. This means that `class LoginConfiguration` needs a method definition for `public GeneralConfigData GetConfig()`, and  `class AppConfiguration` needs a method defintion for both `public GeneralConfigData GetConfig()` as well as `LoginConfigData GetConfig()`.

So fine. I do that. Now, in my application-specific modules, I get a compiler error. Up in my class field definitions, I have `private IAppConfiguration _appConfiguration;`. Later in a method, I make a reference to it:

```
var element = _appConfiguration.GetConfig().AppSpecificConfigElement;
```

The compiler is confused, saying

> the call is ambiguous between the following or properties 'IConfiguration.GetConfig()' and 'IConfiguration.GetConfig()'

Why doesn't the compiler see that the type is `IAppConfiguration` and define the call to `GetConfig()` to the `AppConfiguration`'s `GetConfig()` (where `T` is defined as `AppConfigData`)?

Is there an obvious way to disambiguate the call to `GetConfig()` using my scheme?

Comment: Try this:
`var element = ((IConfiguration<AppConfigData>)_appConfiguration).GetConfig().AppSpecificConfigElement;`

Comment: Also, as a side note, what you just did will make lives of whoever comes after you severely miserable. Configuration objects should be POCOs, or at max POCOs with a simple interface (and even that only when you're stuck with classic .net and something desktop like).
That allow them to be injected as needed from any source (db, text file, json, external source) by means of IoC framework. if you need inheritance, you simply have `Config1 : Config2` and `Config2 : Config3` chains, and passe the same instance to the IoC.

Comment: I don't get this part of the abstract `ConfigurationBase<T>` class: `protected ConfigData Config { get; set; }` If anything, it should be `protected T Config { get; set; }`.

Comment: @zaitsman Some of the details are lost in the complexity of the question. The implemented `IConfiguration` inheritance chain serves two purposes. (1) to expose the Config POCO at that layer and (2) to expose config methods specific to that layer, e.g. `SaveLoginConfig()` for `ILoginConfiguration` and `LoadUserProfile()` for `IAppConfiguration`. I didn't include that in the question since I was afraid it would muddy the details but it is definitely helpful to know *why* I am doing it this way.

Comment: Also, @zaitsman, your suggestion totally syntactically works, but casting defeats the purpose of all of this complexity. It looks like you generally believe this complexity is more hurtful than helpful (which you may totally right). I was considering placing this question on softwareengineering SE or CodeReview SE to get people's opinions.

Comment: @ZoharPeled see two comments above - the point was that each layer of complexity (general vs. login vs. app) would both (1) expose the config object specific to that layer and (2) expose configuration-like methods specific to that layer. The `Config` is protected since I don't want it to be publicly set, but I do want it accessible to child classes. The `public T GetConfig()` was intended to be a convenience thing so that if I knew I was working with the login or app layer, I would automatically get a reference to the `ConfigData` element that was already casted to the appropriate type.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz check out `explicit interface implementation`. That or type casting are really your only options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then what you just did is that you have two methods that have same signature except for the return value which cannot be resolved automatically. Compiler doesn't (and cannot) traverse all subclasses derived from `ConfigData` to determine that `AppSpecificConfigElement` belongs to `AppConfiguration` and pick overload based on that - even if it did you can have multiple classes that have `AppSpecificConfigElement` property so it won't be much wiser. You need to help compiler understand what you need, either by typing `_appConfiguration` to proper type or using typed descendant of `ConfigData` instead of `var` in your statement first and then get property.

In both cases I think you seriously over-engineered and I would suggest to step back and reconsider your approach. As @zaitsman said these objects should be [POCOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) and have different loader (DB, filesystem, ...) implementing simple `Load`/`Save` interface that can be then passed to DI based on context.

Comment: You get the credit for pointing out that what I want is not possible. It's one thing to go to the internet and ask, _Can X do Y?_, but it requires so much more knowledge and research to confidently say _X cannot do Y_.